# Width of DataGridColumn is not taking up all space

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I would like my `DataGrid` columns to take up all the remaining space available to them but be equally as wide. I have used `Width = "*"` in the past, but for whatever reason it isn't working in this case. This is the code for the `DataGrid` so far;

```
        <Grid Grid.Column="4" Grid.RowSpan="2" Margin="10" MaxHeight="325">
            <DataGrid x:Name="bnumDataGrid" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="4" ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentBnumsCollectionView}" 
                      CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionChanged="BnumDataGridSelectionChanged">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Job ID" Width="*" Binding="{Binding JobID}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Job Description" Width="*" Binding="{Binding JobDescription}"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </Grid>
```

This results in the columns looking like this;

[image]

I really cannot understand why they aren't taking up the rest of the available space when I have used a similar `DataGrid` even on the same page that is doing what I want it to. I thought it could be to do with it's parent - it's contained inside a `Grid` but after some playing around with the Grid I couldn't get it to take up space either.

Comment: Your `DataGrid` appears to be inside a `Grid`. Is the screenshot of just the `DataGrid` or the whole view? If it's the latter then what else is in the `Grid` will be affecting the space available.

Comment: @ChrisF Thanks for your answer. It is inside a `Grid`. Nothing else is inside the `Grid`. I'll update my answer with the `Grid` code too. I'm still not sure why a `Grid` would affect the width of the columns, shouldn't the width of the `DataGrid` be affected? In my eyes the columns should still go up to the width of the `DataGrid`.

Answer (score 0):

in my view, the reason why it happens is not the DataGrid, but your Layout. For example this layout perfectly works:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <DataGrid >
       <DataGrid.Columns>
         <DataGridTextColumn Header="Job ID" Width="*" Binding="{Binding JobID}"/>
         <DataGridTextColumn Header="Job Description" Width="*" Binding="{Binding JobDescription}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
 </DataGrid>
```

What I see is:

[image]

Comment: @stepup It's a bit better with `Width="Auto"` however it still isn't perfect. There is now just a blank third column which I want to be taken over by the first two. Also when I scroll down as the Data is longer the columns 'grow' - not exactly ideal.

Comment: Setting a `MinWidth` on the DataGrid fixed it for me!